# What type of fungus is this?

Tags: identification, houseplants, fungus

[image: Fungus image 1]
[image: Fungus image 2]
[image: Fungus image 3]

What fungus is this? It looks like baby-mushrooms.

Comment: Hi 4-K! Some more details may help with identification. What plant is it growing on? Is the plant otherwise healthy? How long has it been there? Is it spreading? Does it smell? Is this the first time you've seen it? Is it spongy, or firm? Can you see roots? What's the general temperature range? Has anything changed, like soil, lighting or watering routine? Please add anything else you can think of into the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Sue Plant is not so healthy. It is growing on the rind of ridge gourd(peel only). Didn't smell it. just noticed it the day of posting the question. Didn't touch it, was afraid. didn't look for roots either :D. temp range is warm here. Soil didn't change. It rained a lot in a span of a week or two. They are in the balcony.

Comment: Did the mushrooms get any larger? Any developmental changes would be helpful, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a slime mold possibly in the genus *Trichia* or *Hemitrichia*.

[image]

Comment: Is there any low-tech test OP can do to confirm the fruiting bodies are multi-cellular amoebae instead of mushrooms?

Comment: Is it good/bad for the soil/plant?